# Cauchy's one-line notation for sum over ordered permutations.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation, permutations

**Setup:** I would like to use [Cauchy's 1-line notation for permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_notations) to express the following kind of sum more compactly:

\begin{align} 
C_{1,2} C_{3,4}+C_{1,3}C_{2,4}+C_{1,4}C_{2,3}, \tag{*}\label{*}
\end{align}
where $C_{i,j}$ are some indexed coefficients.  i.e., all the perumutations of $C_{i,j}C_{k,l}$ for $i,j,k,l=1,2,3,4$ with $i<j$, $k<l$, and $i<k$.

**Example:** If my sum had instead been over products like $C_{i,j}D_{k,l}$ with permutations of $i,j,k,l=1,2,3,4$ with no ordering restriction, then I could compactly write,

\begin{align}
\sum_\sigma C_{\sigma(1),\sigma(2)}D_{\sigma(3),\sigma(4)},
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ denotes the permutations of $1,2,3,4$.

**Question:**  To generate \eqref{*}, I need to take into account the fact that $C_{i,j}C_{k,l}=C_{k,l}C_{i,j}$ and implement the ordering restriction.  Is there a compact way to achieve this using Cauchy's 1-line notation (and perhaps other "standard" combinatoric notation/conventions)?

Comment: Could you maybe explain what $C_{i,j}$ is exactly?

Comment: Perhaps they could be [Plucker coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates) in a quadratic relation